# White HTML page after redirection with Django CBV model

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm getting an issue and I don't find a way to solve this problem.
All seems to be fine, but it doesn't work.

This is the process :

I have a template with all informations about the object which is just created by Django form.
I have a button which have to redirect to an other template taking account the `object id` but when I'm redirect to this template, I'm getting an html white page.

This is my model :

```
class Societe(models.Model):

    NumeroIdentification            = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, verbose_name='Numero Identification physique', unique=True)
    Nom                             = models.CharField(null= False, max_length=30, verbose_name='Nom de Société')
    Etat                            = models.CharField(max_length = 30, choices = CHOIX_ETAT_SOCIETE, null=False, verbose_name="Etat")
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('SocieteResume', kwargs={'id': self.id})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode (self.id, self.NumeroIdentification, self.Nom, ...)
```

I have a first class which let to display created object in detail :

```
class IdentitySocieteResumeView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView) :

    template_name = 'Identity_Societe_Resume.html'
    model = Societe

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) :

        context_data = super(IdentitySocieteResumeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        id = self.kwargs['id']
        societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id)

        obj = Societe.objects.filter (Nom=societe.Nom, SIRET=societe.SIRET, SIREN=societe.SIREN, Ville=societe.Ville)

        if obj:
            sc_obj = obj[0] 

            ...

        return context_data
```

With the associated template which has this button in order to redirect to the next template :

```
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'SocietePDF' societe.id %}">{% csrf_token %}
{% csrf_token %}
<button>Générer le PDF de la Fiche d'Identification </button>
</form>
```

This button redirects to (I have to get the `id` in order to have personalize view/template) :

```
class IdentitySocietePDFCreatingView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView) :

    template_name = 'Identity_Societe_PDF.html'
    model = Societe

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) :

        context_data = super(IdentitySocietePDFCreatingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        id = self.kwargs['id']
        societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id)

        obj = Societe.objects.filter (Nom=societe.Nom, SIRET=societe.SIRET, SIREN=societe.SIREN, Ville=societe.Ville)

        ...

        return context_data
```

My urls.py file looks like this :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from Identity.views import IdentityIndividuFormView, IdentityHomepageView, IdentityChoiceUpdateView, IdentitySocieteFormView, IdentitySocieteResumeView, IdentitySocietePDFCreatingView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^Homepage$', IdentityHomepageView.as_view(), name="Home"),
    url(r'^Person/ChoiceUpdate/$', IdentityChoiceUpdateView.as_view(), name="IdentityChoice"),
    url(r'^Person/Form/$', IdentityIndividuFormView.as_view(), name="IndividuFormulaire"),
    url(r'^Company/Form/$', IdentitySocieteFormView.as_view(), name = "SocieteFormulaire"),
    url(r'^Person/Form/Resume/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.IdentityIndividuResume, name="IndividuResume"),
    url(r'^Company/Form/Resume/(?P<id>\d+)/$', IdentitySocieteResumeView.as_view(), name="SocieteResume"),
    url(r'^Person/Update/$', views.IdentityIndividuUpdateAll, name="Edition"),
    url(r'^Company/Update/$', views.IdentitySocieteUpdateAll, name="EditionSociete"),
    url(r'^Person/Research/$', views.IdentityIndividuResearching, name="IndividuRecherche"),
    url(r'^Company/Research/$', views.IdentitySocieteResearching, name="SocieteRecherche"),
    url(r'^Company/Research/Fraud/$', views.IdentitySocieteFraudResearching, name="SocieteRechercheFraude"),
    url(r'^Company/Research/Employe/$', views.IdentitySocieteEmploye, name="SocieteRechercheEmploye"),
    url(r'^Person/Read/PDF/$', views.IdentityIndividuPDFReading, name="Consultation"),
    url(r'^Company/Read/PDF/$', views.IdentitySocietePDFReading, name="SocieteConsultation"),
    url(r'^Person/Delete/$', views.IdentityIndividuDelete, name="Suppression"),
    url(r'^Person/Form/PDF/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.IdentityIndividuPDFCreating, name="IndividuPDF"),
    url(r'^Company/Form/PDF/(?P<id>\d+)/$', IdentitySocietePDFCreatingView.as_view(), name="SocietePDF"),
    url(r'^Statistics/$', views.IdentityStatistics, name="Statistiques"),
    url(r'^Person/Update/Civility/$', views.IdentityIndividuUpdateCivility, name="EditionCivilite"),
    url(r'^Person/Update/Coordonates/$', views.IdentityIndividuUpdateCoordonates, name="EditionCoordonnees"),
    url(r'^Person/Update/Contact/$', views.IdentityIndividuUpdateContact, name="EditionContact"),
]
```

The strange thing is : when I click on button in order to be redirect to `SocietePDF` I'm getting a white HTML page, but If I cut/paste the url, I can access to the template.

Something is missing in my process ?

Thank you !

Comment: En anglais pour "blanc" dans le sens de "vide" on dit bien "blank" et non pas "white".

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok I'm sorry I mean my html page was all white, but blank is more adapted ^^ I didn't know you spoke French langage ;)

Comment: I have many talents...:) anyway, one thing I would try would be to change the form action from POST to GET, since your IdentitySocietePDFCreatingView doesn't expect a POST request.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're right one more time ! As I'm trying to migrate FBV to CBV, I didn't pay attention to this form method. Thank you !

Maybe you could add your comment as an answer and I will validate your answer as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IdentitySocietePDFCreatingView is not expecting a POST request; you should change the form action to GET.